# Unable to use sum function with derived table result

Tags: sql-server, select, aggregate-functions

> I have a homework question asking me to create a select statement to
>   calculate the total cost of the accounting software packages
>   installed in 1998 on each
>   computer that belongs to the accounting department

I have been able to find the software packages and their costs matching these requirements using the following statement.

```
select pack, softcost from software where year(instdate) = 1998 and pack in 
 (select pack from package where PAcKTYPE = 'accounting') and TAGNUM in 
  (select TAGNUM from pc where location = 'sales')
```

however, when I try to calculate the sum of of these softcosts using the following statement I receive an error stating  "Column 'software.SOFTCOST' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

```
select sum(SOFTCOST) from
(select pack, softcost from software where year(instdate) = 1998 and pack in 
 (select pack from package where PAcKTYPE = 'accounting') and TAGNUM in 
  (select TAGNUM from pc where location = 'sales') group by pack) as table1
```

Could someone lead me in the right direction? I have attached my results from the first select statement and the data from my database below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In your inner query you're trying to `select pack, softcost` but only `group by pack`. You either need to `sum(softcost)` at that point or `group by softcost` - whichever suits your needs.

Comment: Start learning best practices - many of which will avoid logic errors that are difficult to find. Give every table an alias (short but useful, not a single character) and use it when referencing any column. Always reference tables with the appropriate schema name. Lastly look at your requirements. Now look again. Computers that belong to **Accounting** department?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single column in your out most select and the grouping is not necessary. remove the group by you should be fine